# How to make HTML 5's Geo Location less accurate?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently using html 5's geo location feature. Everything works and its a good feature. However, as counter intuitive this may sound, I want the location which it obtains to be less accurate.

At the moment, it is getting my exact location, and, due to data privacy, I dont want this. Is there a way to make it less accurate ?

I am currently trying to create a function called getRandomGeoValue, shown below:

```
function getRandomGeoValue(geoValue)
{


}
```

The function takes a geo value (either latitude or longitude) and returns an random inaccurate geo value. I am trying to use Javascripts Math.random() function, but the result is way too inaccurate.

Ideally, the inaccuracy would be around 17 miles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the current location (presumably latitude and longitude) and apply one of several transformations to it:

1. Round it to the nearest 10 miles (or whatever level of accuracy you want)
2. Round each latitude and longitude value to the nearest 10 seconds (or whatever level of accuracy you want)
3. Add a random value to both the latitude and longitude that makes it +/- 5 miles (or whatever level of accuracy you want).

If your lat/long values are in degrees, then you can round it to the nearest N miles with this function:

```
function roundPosition(lat, lon, roundMiles) {
    // 69.11 miles per degree of latitude
    var roundFactor = 69.11 / roundMiles;
    lat = Math.round(lat * roundFactor) / roundFactor;

    // miles in 1 degree of longitude = 69.11 * cos(latitude in radians)
    var latRadians = (lat / 180) * Math.PI;
    var milesPerDegreeLong = 69.11 * Math.cos(latRadians);
    roundFactor = milesPerDegreeLong / roundMiles;
    lon = Math.round(lon * roundFactor) / roundFactor;
    return({latitude: lat, longitude: lon});
}
```

This function returns an object with the new rounded latitude and longitude as properties.

Example usage:

```
var latitude = 69.2;
var longitude = 180.9;
var newPos = roundPosition(latitude, longitude, 17);
// newPos.latitude and newPos.longitude contain the new rounded values
```

Comment: @user1724140 - Longitude and Latitude can be represented in degrees, minutes, seconds.  One second of Longitude at the equator is about 100 feet.  So rounding to the nearest second would reduce the precision to about 50 feet.  Rounding to one minute would reducing the precision to about 1/2 mile.  Longitude can also be specified in radians or in degrees and decimal minutes such as 180 degrees, 50.4 minutes.  You can always convert from one to the other.

Comment: any idea how I can convert a longitude/ latitude value to time in Javascript by any chance? I have a function randomiseGeoVal which takes a lat or long value and returns a randomised value. (I would be calling this method twice, once for the long and another for the lat) So how would you convert the value to time please?

Comment: @user1724140 - what do you mean "convert to time"?  Degrees, minutes, seconds is not time - it's a position.  What units is your lat/long value?  Is it radians?  degrees?

Comment: @user1724140 - What level of accuracy do you want in the resulting position in feet or miles?

Comment: @user1724140 - I added a roundPosition() function to my answer.  Specify the latitude and longitude in decimal degrees and the desired precision in miles.

Comment: Great, it worked thanks. Just one thing, you forgot to add the opening bracket when initialising latRadians. Other than that, its great. Thanks again :)